# Cannot redeclare classX in classX.php?

Tags: php, class, redeclare

I've searched for similar questions but didn't find any. The usual problem is that a certain class cannot be redeclared in another class, and so the solution is to use "require_once" or "include_once". But my error is not allowing the class itself to redeclared!

Let me explain, I have two classes, `Design` and `DesignSide`.
I have a bunch of PHP files where I use these two classes.
- build_design.php,
- browse_designs.php, which gives an AJAX call to
- load_designs.php

Each design can have a few sides to it, so all 3 files above include the line:

```
require_once("Design.php");
```

and `Design.php` has the line:

```
require_once("DesignSide.php");
```

But on build_design.php, my error is:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class DesignSide in ../classes/DesignSide.php on line 4
```

i.e. it's objecting to DesignSide declaring itself! These are the beginning lines of DesignSide:

```
<?php

class DesignSide
{
private $id;
private $data;
private $designtag;
private $side;
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Does `Design.php` call `DesignSide` somewhere?

Comment: Missing quotation on file name in require_once function

Comment: I actually did have the quotations in my code - just edited the question to include them.

Comment: How does AJAX fit into this mix?
More info usually gives more accurate answers.

Comment: What are the starting lines of `build_design.php` and `load_designs.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...or else you can use one of PHP's magic [`__autoload`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) in your scripts to prevent this kind of behavior.

**Save this file as config.php**

```
function __autoload( $class ) {
    if( file_exists( $class . '.php' ) ) {
        require_once $class . '.php';
    } else {
        die( 'No such file.' );
    }
}
```

Now, include/require `config.php` in all your files and you don't need to include/require the class files.

Only caveat is that the class names must match the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Someone just deleted their answer - but I was just coming to tick it as the right answer.
It turned out that in fact I did have "DesignSide.php" included twice, in `build_design.php`.
Thanks! My bad!

So the correct answer was to include the DesignSide class in Design, and only include the Design class in the three php files.